# How to use inputAccessoryViewController in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

In iOS 8 Apple introduced a new property under `UIResponder` called `inputAccessoryViewController`. However there has been no documentation explaining how one can use it.

Moreover, in iOS 8, setting the `inputAccessoryView` property of a `UIViewController` subclass and making the subclass the first responder seems to cause the view controller to leak.

My question is: How can I use an `inputAccessoryViewController` in a `UIViewController` subclass? Does that solve the memory leak problem?

Comment: You were using a `UIInputViewController` in your `UIViewController` custom subclass as `inputAccessoryViewController`, and which one wasn't deallocated ?

Comment: Show actual code, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use inputAccessoryViewController, you need to subclass any UITextView or UITextField controls and override the inputAccessoryViewController property readwrite.

```
@interface MyTextView: UITextView

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIInputViewController *inputAccessoryViewController;

@end
```

Note that the view controller you provide should be a UIInputViewController (which will give you access to input delegate and text document information) and will create the 'inputView' (as self.view) if you call [super loadView], which you can add your subviews to.  This UIInputView will be styled appropriately for the keyboard.  I haven't experimented with trying to load from .xib in this case.

I also found to properly size the inputView (and avoid a bunch of constraint errors), I added the following code

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.superview.frame), myAccessoryHeight);
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this method in your code. This will help you. from iOS 7 you need to return UIView only as accessoryView.

```
-(UIView *)inputAccessoryView{ 
       UIView  *accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:toolView.frame];
      toolView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);  
      [accessoryView addSubview:toolView];  
      return accessoryView; 
}
```